# Functions did not deploy properly

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, google-cloud-functions

I am a bit new in cloud functions stuff and trying to deploy my website on firebase but getting this error while deploying cloud functions.

```
!  functions[sendMail(us-central1)]: Deployment error.
Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Error: please examine your function logs to see the error cause: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs
!  functions[app(us-central1)]: Deployment error.
Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Error: please examine your function logs to see the error cause: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs
Error: Functions did not deploy properly.
```

these functions are working fine on localhost as well

Comment: It's going to be worth your time looking at those logs, I'd say. Check out the URL (https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs) mentioned in the error.

Comment: thanks mate, its resolved now i actually didn't synced package.json and package-lock.json

Answer (score 3):

From the comments above:

The issue was that the *package.json* and *package-lock.json* were not correctly synchronized.

Comment: how do you synchronise that?

Comment: Delete node_modules, reinstall. If that doesn't work, also remove package-lock.json or yarn.lock and reinstall.

Answer (score 2):

You can examine the issue by viewing the log

```
firebase functions:log
```

The specific issue will be visible there. I sometimes had error as simple as a missing package

another time the logs didn't help and I found the problem to be that I had disabled billing for the project for debugging.

It then worked fine after I enabled it in the `Google cloud console`.

It would have been really helpful if firebase could show any useful error message to suggest the problem. I found this after wasting time on many trials.